# Sync users data from PHP to meteor application

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, meteor

I have two applications, one in PHP and other in Meteor, My requirement is that when a user is created using PHP application, it should be also sync/add to the meteor application.

I have knowledge in meteor, but not in PHP, I am looking for creating a method in PHP, so that it can send a http or similar request with all user information to my meteor application(method), and here I can query for existing user or add a new one, is this approach possible or have some other way possible, if possible then please give me an idea how I can send request from the PHP side and get this request in meteor and accomplish my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Create a function in PHP that would do a POST request using curl and it will send the data to and endpoint where your meteor application will take over. You can google how to send POST requests from PHP and the first link will give you an answer.

Just make an endpoint ready from your meteor app to receive the data from PHP app.